# Declarar una variable en base a un condicional

Tags: python, variables, condiciones

Estoy intentando declarar una variable en base a un condicional, el siguiente código es una idea que ilustra la intención:

```
import numpy as np

a = 23
b = 54
c = 60

    Qs = if a < b:
        Qs = 1
    elif a < b < c:
        Qs = 1.4*a
    else:
        Qs = 0.69*b
```

Aquí una imagen de dicho código en MathCad, para ilustrar la intención.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes declarar una variable de esta forma `Qs = if a < b:` pues te arrojara error

```
import numpy as np

a = 23
b = 54
c = 60
Qs = 0

if a < b:
    Qs = 1
elif a < b < c:
    Qs = 1.4*a
else:
    Qs = 0.69*b

print(Qs)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Qs = if a < b:` es sintaxis inválida porque la expresión `if a < b` no retorna nada que se pueda asociar a `Qs` y en Python una variable siempre tiene que estar asociada a una referencia a un objeto en memoria.

La sintaxis que intentas usar es parecida al "operador ternario":

```
Qs = 1 if a < b else 1.4 * a if a < b < c else 0.69 * b
```

El operador `:=` que usas en MathCad en Python existe a partir de Python 3.8, pero es lo que se conoce como operador *walrus*<sup>1</sup> o expresiones de asignación. Permite asignar valores a una variable dentro de una expresión:

```
n = 13
if (resto:= n % 13) == 0:
    print(f"{n} es divisible entre 13")
else:
    print(f"{n} no es divisible entre 13, resto {resto}")
```

---

```
while (palabra:= input('Ingrese una palabra o "q" para salir: ')) != "q":
    print(palabra)
```

<sup>1</sup> Morsa, en inglés.